# Count of Distinct Items by cumulative grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this following query which takes distinct item count for each owner, grouped by every month

## Query:

```
SELECT owner, Month(date) AS month, Count(DISTINCT( item )) AS cnt
        FROM   table_name
        WHERE  impact < 3
               AND group IN ( 'Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3')
               AND date >= '2019-01-01'
               AND date <= '2019-05-02 23:59:59'
        GROUP  BY owner, month
        ORDER  BY owner, month;
```

This produces count of distinct items for each owner for each month. What I want is count of distinct items for each owner for cumulative months. For Feb, I want count of distinct items for each owner from Jan to Feb. For March, I want count of distinct items for each owner from Jan to March and so on. Can someone please help as how this has to be done?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a cumulative count based on the *first time* that the item appears for an owner.  In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT owner, Month(date) AS month,
       COUNT(*) as this_month_cnt,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY owner ORDER BY MONTH(date)) as running_cnt
FROM  (SELECT t.owner, t.item, MIN(t.date) as date
       FROM table_name
       WHERE impact < 3 AND
             group IN ( 'Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3') AND
             date >= '2019-01-01' AND
             date < '2019-05-03'
       GROUP  BY owner, item
      ) t
GROUP BY owner, month
ORDER  BY owner, month;
```